# How to hidden password from groovy tp bash?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
stages {
    stage('Get Clone ') {
        steps {
     sh """

               ./scripts/login_to_cf.sh  -user ${params.USERNAME} -password ${params.PASSWORD} -           
            """         

            }
        }
    }
```

When I call to the script I can see the password .
How it could be hidden or secured ?

Comment: Update `login_to_cf.sh` to read the password from a file, or standard in.

Comment: You can choose `Password Parameter` type for this parameter and Jenkins will mask it with `*` in jenkins console output, or you can use Stepniak's solution at following answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Jenkins Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin). First, you need to add credentials. To do so go to your Jenkins job folder and click on **Credentials** on the left sidebar. Next click on **(global)** credentials domain and click on **Add credentials**. Choose **Username with password** credentials type and pass your *username* and *password*.

[image]

You can keep *ID* field empty - Jenkins will generate UUID in place, so when you add it, go to **Edit** view of the credentials so you can copy credentials ID.

Now you can use this username and password in Jenkins jobs located in the folder. In Jenkins pipeline you use `withCredentials()` step to inject credentials. Take a look at the following exemplary pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 

    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '2480f22e-52b4-40df-a6f4-ab346769d694', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
                    sh "echo --help -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I inject credentials with *ID* `2480f22e-52b4-40df-a6f4-ab346769d694` and I store username in `USERNAME` variable, and password in `PASSWORD` variable. The good thing about using `withCredentials()` is that Jenkins takes care of replacing username and password with `****` in the console log, so your password does not leak with the console log. *(It only affects the console log and the command you execute receives correct credentials.)*

```sh
[Pipeline] node
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo --help -u **** -p ****
--help -u **** -p ****
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Terminated
Finished: SUCCESS
```